# input file style does not work in bootbox confirm

Tags: jquery, input, styles, bootbox

I have File input style that work properly in my entire website except when I use it inside bootbox.

Bootbox code:

```
function bootbox_file(att) {
bootbox.confirm("Add New Diagnosis Letter<form class='form-horizontal' enctype='multipart/form-data' id='infos' action='#' method='post'>\
        <br/>Upload File:  <input name='letter' id='id-input-file-2' type='file'>\
         \
        </form>", function(result) {
            if(result){
                       $('#infos').submit();
                   }
    });
}
```

jquery file code:

```
$('#id-input-file-2').ace_file_input({
    no_file:'No File ...',
    btn_choose:'Choose',
    btn_change:'Change',
    droppable:false,
    onchange:null,
    thumbnail:false //| true | large
    //whitelist:'gif|png|jpg|jpeg'
    //blacklist:'exe|php'
    //onchange:''
    //
});
```

Any Ideas, Thank you.

Comment: need to intialize plugin within `show` callback. You are likely trying to initialize before the element exists

Comment: thx for the comment, can you write a simple show callback code, coz i don't know where to initialize it. @charlietfl

Comment: in boostrap docs, look for the `show` callback for modal. bootbox just wraps the bootstrap API

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @charlietfl for direction.

I wrote this code and it worked for me:

```
function bootbox_file() {
bootbox_confirm("<form class='form-horizontal' enctype='multipart/form-data' id='infos' action='#'>\
        <br/><input name='letter' type='file'>\
         \
        </form>", 'Upload', 'Cancel').modal('show');
}

function bootbox_confirm(msg, callback_success, callback_cancel) {
var d = bootbox.confirm({message:msg, title:"Upload New Letter", show:false, callback:function(result) {
    if (result)
        console.log("Hi ");
    else if(typeof(callback_cancel) == 'function')
        callback_cancel();
}});

d.bind('shown.bs.modal', function(){
    d.find("input:file").ace_file_input();
});
return d;
}
```